# Recreating a sentence from the original positions on python

Tags: python

I have searched far and wide yet cannot find a solution to my task. I need to be able to get the positions of words from an input and then save that and the words (with duplicates removed) into a notepad file. Then, I need to be able to bring these positions back in and recreate the sentence. Yet, this has to be done Python. To make it clearer I'll use an example using the code I have already written:

-The input-

```
Would you like to compress or decompress a file? c/d: C
Please type your string using only letters and punctuation: the dog was a dog that jumped over a log
Positions saved to file. Ending code
```

-The Result-

```
1 2 3 4 2 5 6 7 4 8 

the dog was a that jumped over log
```

The problem I am having is that I cannot recreate the sentence from these numbers or words as I do not understand how to complete this. The code I have so far for this last bit is as follows:

```
    #
    posFile = open ("positions.txt", "r")   #Opens and reads the file with the positions saved
    posFileStr = posFile.read()
    wordFile.close()
    posFile.close()


    #
    word_list = (wordList)                  #Opens and reads the file with the unique words saved
    word_index = (posFileStr)

    recreated = ' '.join([word_list[i-1] for i in word_index])
    positions = [wordList.index(word) for word in sentence]

    print (recreated)
    print (positions)
```

Comment: When you read the file, all you get is a string. You will need to convert that string into an array first. You might want to take a look at [``split()``](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#str.split). In case of your ``word_index`` you should also make sure it's an array of ``int``, not an array of ``str``!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is incomplete, so there's nothing to fix/suggest.

This line looks fine to me:

```
recreated = ' '.join([word_list[i-1] for i in word_index])
```

which means that word_index is missing words.

Note: you don't need brackets for that list comprehension above. If you omit them, you get a generator that join iterates over without first allocating a whole new list. Example: `' '.join(a for a in b)`

Here's a solution. Hopefully, it'll help you see the mistake in your code.

```
In [3]: s = 'the dog was a dog that jumped over a log'

In [17]: i = 1
    ...: d = {}
    ...: words = []
    ...: sentence = []
    ...: for w in s.split():
    ...:     if w not in d:
    ...:         d[w] = i
    ...:         i += 1
    ...:         words.append(w)
    ...:     sentence.append(d[w])
    ...:

In [18]: words
Out[18]: ['the', 'dog', 'was', 'a', 'that', 'jumped', 'over', 'log']

In [19]: sentence
Out[19]: [1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 5, 6, 7, 4, 8]

In [20]: ' '.join(words[i - 1] for i in sentence)
Out[20]: 'the dog was a dog that jumped over a log'

In [21]:
```

Comment: Thank you! I was able to use what you gave me to go back to my code and rewrite part ofit to do what was needed.